# How to record data for distance measurement using Banner Q4XTBLAF300-Q8 laser sensor with NI USB 6008 in Python?

Tags: python, output, distance, sensors, nidaqmx

I had connected the analog voltage output to the analog input pin of NI USB 6008. However, the voltage shows no difference when the distance varying.

Trying the other ways of getting the analog output data, eg. time flight etc., but don't know how to start it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the [manual] (https://info.bannerengineering.com/cs/groups/public/documents/literature/181483.pdf) mentioning the analog output but the PNP output. Have you tried to capture the output signal with DMM or scope?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use a multimeter to measure the output voltage, but it is still the same, no voltage difference with distance measured varies.

Comment: In that case, I don't think it has anything to do with the DMM or the DAQ. You might want to check the wiring for the sensor or reach out to Banner for support to figure out why the sensor is not outputting any voltage.